# Unique solution of LP

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, simplex

Hi I am working on the following question:

> If $c \in int(N_P(x))$, then $x$ is a unique solution.

I have proven that this is true if $x$ is a vertex. Well I am wondering if the following is a counter example: Let $Q=[-1,1]^2$. Choose $x=(1,0)$. Then $N_Q(x)=pos((1,0))$ where $pos$ is the positive hull. Since $aff(x)=lin((1,0)^T)$ ($aff,lin$ the affine respectively linear space) $c=(1,0) \in int(N_Q(x))$, but $x'=(1,0.5)$ is also an optimal solution.

> Consider the LP max $c^Tx,x \in P$, where $c \in \mathbb{R^n}$  and $P= \{x \in \mathbb{R^n}: Ax \leq b \}$ is a fulldimensional polyhedron with $A\in \mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R^m}$ Moreover let $x \in P$. 
>   If $c \in int(N_P(x))$ then there exists a unique dual optimal solution. True or False?

Probably not if the primal has no unique solution the dual won't.

Is it possible to conlcude the primal has a unique solution if and only if the dual has?

Comment: What exactly is $N_P(x)$?

Comment: Its the outer normal cone

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367285/notion-of-outer-normal-cone-and-supporting-cone-if-x-in-relintc

Comment: and $P$? Btw. each question should be self contained. Uncommon notation  should be explained.

Comment: I take the unit cube is $[0,1]^2$, right? You got $N_P(x)$ wrong in you example, as $(1, -\alpha)^T$ is also in $N_P(x)$ for $\alpha > 0$. In fact $N_p(x) = [0,\infty) \times (-\infty, 0]$. Thus, your $c$ is a boundary point.

Comment: I don't agree that $(1,-a)^T$ for $a>0$ is in $N_P$ because for $c=(1,-a)$ we have $c(0,-1)^T > c(0,1)^T$

Comment: I asked you what your unit cube is ...

Comment: Well I meant $[-1,1]^2$. If you take  $[0,1]^2 $than the outer normal cone of $(1,0)^T$ is spanned by $(1,0)^T,(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)^T$ would be on the boundary. That's right

Comment: Yes, then your example is correct.

Comment: Okay and do you know anything about the connection of primal dual If it comes to unique solutions

Comment: To go into details, I need to know the exact formulation of your LP. In general, the dual optimizer does not depend on the primal. That is, if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are primal-dual optimal, so are $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$.

Comment: Well I guess we missed that the interior of the normal cone is empty since the normal cone is a 1-dimensional object in a two dimensional space. Therefore the example is not correct. if we exchange $int$ with $relint$ the example would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is it possible to conclude the primal has a unique solution if and
>   only if the dual has?"

There is a way to verify whether LP has unique solution by running another LP.

Appa, G. “On the Uniqueness of Solutions to Linear Programs.” The Journal of the Operational Research Society, vol. 53, no. 10, 2002, pp. 1127–1132., [www.jstor.org/stable/822972](http://www.jstor.org/stable/822972.).

Here is a counter example to the statement that primal unique and dual not.

$$max \ 0x_1+0x_2$$

s.t.

$$-x_1-x_2>=-2 $$
$$0x_1+x_2>=1$$
$$x_1-x_2>=0$$

This LP has unique solution $x_1=x_2=1$;

Dual is given as follows

$$min -2y_1+y_2+0y_3$$

s.t.

$$-y_1+0y_2+y_3=0$$
$$-y_1+y_2-y_3=0$$
$$y_1,y_2,y_3<=0$$

This LP has infinite many feasible solution.